# Get value of tinymce textarea with jquery selector

Tags: jquery-selectors, tinymce

I want to get the value of a tinymce textarea

```
<textarea id="thetextarea"></textarea>
```

on key up in order to feed it into a show-preview script using:

```
function showPreview(value) {

    $("#preview-container").load("/material-preview.php", {s:value});

}
$('thetextarea').live("keyup",function (e) {

        var material = this.value;
        showPreview(material);

        return false;

    });
```

If I try to select the textarea id `thetextarea` it doesnt work (works if I dont make it an tinymce-field).

with firebug I see that the text, when the textarea is tinymce-converted, is in:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody"></body>
```

but this does not work either, (nor does `$('#tinymce')`)

```
 $('mceContentBody').live("keyup",function (e) {

            var material = this.value;
            showPreview(material);

            return false;

        });
```

HTML code (from firebug) after tinyMCE is applied as requested

```
 <textarea id="material-input" class="mceEditor text" style="width: 310px ! important; height: 250px ! important; display: none;" name="material" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
      <span id="material-input_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin" role="application" aria-labelledby="material-input_voice">
      <span id="material-input_voice" class="mceVoiceLabel" style="display:none;">Rich Text Area</span>
      <table id="material-input_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 310px; height: 250px;">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="mceFirst" role="presentation">
          <tr>
          <td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">
            <iframe id="material-input_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT F10 for toolbar. Press ALT 0 for help." style="width: 100%; height: 206px;">
            <html>
             <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
               <body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr">
                  <!-- the text inside tinymce textarea -->
                </body>
            </iframe>
           </td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="mceLast">
         </tbody>
       </table>
    </span>
```

Comment: Solved it with help of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024712/this-keyup-not-responding-when-focused-on-tinymce

Answer (score 76):

Call

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

after that you'll be able to use jquery selector

```
$("#yourtextareaID").val();
```

Comment: in TinyMCE 4 we don't need to add this but in 5 we need to add, can you tell the reason, thanks

Answer (score 24):

```
tinyMCE.get('yourTextAreaId').getContent();
```

Answer (score 3):

See the following link on how to define the onKeyUp event to work with TinyMCE:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onKeyUp

Essentially when you initialize tinyMCE you define your onKeyUp event handler. I think a regular selector won't work here since the text is inside a separate iFrame. The TinyMCE API lists a method `.getContent()` that may work. ie. Something like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {
          //showPreview ( $('.mceContentBody').val() );
          showPreview (tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'}) );

      });
   }
});
```

Also see: 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Your problem is more with TinyMCE than jQuery or Javascript specifically. If the above doesn't work you'll need to read the TinyMCE docs and/or API to figure out how to do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this too.

`tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();`

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE provides a [jQuery pluggin](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php) that you can use in conjunction with the [onKeyUp command in the API](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onKeyUp)

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url : 'path/to/tiny_mce.js',

    theme : "simple",

   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, l) {
          console.debug('Key up event: ' + e.keyCode);
   });
  }
});
```

There is also a [preview plugin,](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apreview) which I suspect does what you were after more directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong in the example above. It should be:

```
$('#thetextarea').live("keyup",function (e) {
```

not

```
$('thetextarea').live("keyup",function (e) {
```

Is this just a typo in your question?

If you're not sure which element has the text you need, you can try adding your event handler to both elements. Also I think you should be using `$(this).val()` vs. `this.val`:

```
$('#thetextarea, .mceContentBody').live("keyup",function (e) {
    var material = $(this).val();
    showPreview(material);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @JJ that was a typo in the question, I also changed to $(this).val() but it does not find it unfortunately.

Comment: Does the keyup event fire? Try adding `alert('event fired');` to see if your event is firing. If so you just need to retrieve the value differently - perhaps via `$('.mceContentBody').val();`

Comment: It does not fire so there is something with the selector. the tinymce makes the textarea into an iframe and put the text directly inside `<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody"></body>
`will that cause any problem for the jquery selector?

Comment: Post the html code (from firebug) as it exists after TinyMCE is applied.

Answer (score 0):

`tinymce.innerHTML` gives me required result

Answer (score 0):

```
//Html text editor text code

 <textarea name="description" class="tinymce" id="texteditor"></textarea>

You can print tinymce text editor code using java script like this.

var content = tinymce.get("texteditor").getContent();
alert(descriptionFieldTxt);

//output
[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]
//output with tags
enter image description here

//Now you can print tinymce texteditor value without p tag like this
var content = tinymce.get("texteditor").getContent({format: "text"});
alert(descriptionFieldTxt);

    enter code here

This code print text without tags
[enter image description here][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgKYg.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb1uf.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahf60.png
```