# Saving data from tinyMCE editor using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, tinymce

I'm making a simple chat using jQuery. The problem is with form? which contains of an input with type "text" and a button. In my JS code I make the button disabled if the text field is empty and enable it when some text is tyoed in it.
It worked properly as I had followig code:

home.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Public chat</title>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Here are the previous messeeges showed, it doesn't matter now-->

    <form id="chat-form" method="post" action="/post/">
        <div id="chat-bottom" class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="chat-msg" name="chat-msg" class="form-control"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <input class="btn btn-default" id="send" type="submit" value="Send"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

<script src="{% static 'chat.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

chat.js:

```
$('#chat-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url : '/post/',
        type : 'POST',
        data : { msgbox : $('#chat-msg').val() },

        success : function(json){
            $('#chat-msg').val('');
            $('#msg-list').append('<li class="text-right list-group-item">' + json.msg + '</li>');
            var chatlist = document.getElementById('msg-list-div');
            chatlist.scrollTop = chatlist.scrollHeight;
        }
    });
});

function getMessages(){
    if (!scrolling) {
        $.get('/messages/', function(messages){
            $('#msg-list').html(messages);
            var chatlist = document.getElementById('msg-list-div');
            chatlist.scrollTop = chatlist.scrollHeight;
        });
    }
    scrolling = false;
}

var scrolling = false;
$(function(){
    $('#msg-list-div').on('scroll', function(){
        scrolling = true;
    });
    refreshTimer = setInterval(getMessages, 500);
});

$(document).ready(function() {//here checking if the text field is empty
     $('#send').attr('disabled','disabled');
     $('#chat-msg').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
        $('#send').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
     });
 });
```

When I tried to add TinyMCE to the text field

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    selector : "#chat-msg"
});
</script>
```

the "Send" button is always disabled. I tried to do like here [Get value of tinymce textarea with jquery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214218/get-value-of-tinymce-textarea-with-jquery-selector) so function looked like this:

```
$('#chat-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();

    $.ajax({
        //here the same code as above in the same function
    });
});
```

and this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#send').attr('disabled','disabled');
     $('#chat-msg').keyup(function() {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
        $('#send').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
     });
 });
```

vut the reault is still the same. At first I didn't want to use getContent() (as it is said in many similiar questions) because in the documentation (http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent) it is said to make cleanup of content. Finally I tried even that with no effect.

I am new both to jQuery and TinyMCE, so I beleive that I'm missing something obvious. How should chat.js be changed here to retreive the content of text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would change is your `keyup` function.  When TinyMCE is injected into the page the original form element (`<input>` in your case) is no longer visible.  If you use your browser tools you will see that TinyMCE injects a series of `<div>`s and an `<iframe>` effectively hiding your `<input>`.  Once you do this the code you have in `document.ready` won't ever trigger:

```
//This won't trigger anything with TinyMCE on the page
$('#chat-msg').keyup(function() {  
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    if($(this).val() != '') {
       $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
    $('#send').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
 });
```

Instead you can add a `keyup` or `change` function to TinyMCE's init function:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
       editor.on('change', function () {
           //Perform your updating of the button here
       });
       editor.on('keyup', function () {
           //Perform your updating of the button here
       });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case tinyMCE.triggerSave(); was not working so I set the content manually at onChange Event . you can do it like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    selector : "#chat-msg"
    setup: function (editor) {
       editor.on('change', function () {
           var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().trim();
           var tinyMceElement = tinyMCE.get(editor.editorId).getElement();
            $(tinyMceElement).html(content);
       });
});
</script>
```

Note :  var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().trim();
        var tinyMceElement = tinyMCE.get(editor.editorId).getElement();

This is the way to get text content and the dom element in old tinyMce it may be diffrent in new Version.