# Form Input versus Textarea Input with AJAX submission to mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an PHP/AJAX update that works fine with a "text input" box.

But when I change it to a "textarea" box, it no longer works,

See the code below:

THIS WORKS FINE:

```
echo '<input id="bodytext" value="'.htmlentities(stripslashes($bodytext)).'">';
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
echo '<textarea id="bodytext" value="'.htmlentities(stripslashes($bodytext)).'">'.htmlentities(stripslashes($bodytext)).'</textarea>';
```

THIS IS THE AJAX CODE:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#update").click(function(){
    var bodytext=$("#bodytext").val();
       $.ajax({
          url:'update.php',
          method:'POST',
          data:{
              bodytext:bodytext
          },
          success:function(response){
          alert(response);
          }
       });
     });
     });
</script>
```

THIS IS THE UPDATE.PHP FILE:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
$bodytext=$_POST["bodytext"];

$sql="UPDATE doc SET bodytext='$bodytext' WHERE id=1";

if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "DATA updated Yes ".$bodytext;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry - I was doing an edit - patience my friend.

Comment: Please add the errors you are getting to the question.

Comment: You mentioned below that you use apply tinyMCE plugin with that textarea, I believe this thread will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214218/get-value-of-tinymce-textarea-with-jquery-selector

Comment: A `textarea` does not have a `value` attribute - the content goes between open and close tags - ie: `<textarea>data</textarea>`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In javascript:
If you use input tag, you get val of input

```
$("#bodytext").val()
```

But you use textarea, you should get html or text because it not have attribute value

```
$("#bodytext").html() or $("#bodytext").text()
```

Comment: I changed the var bodytext=$("#bodytext").val(); to var bodytext=$("#bodytext").html(); --- still not recognizing it - not working.

Comment: text in javascript when call $("#bodytext").html() and value when post back to server $_POST["bodytext"] ?

Comment: I agree that `textarea` does not have the `value` attribute but JQuery `.val()` still can be used with textarea, it will return the text between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` https://jsfiddle.net/vmky75z3/

Comment: I post back to server in the update.php file - I dont see any code in that file like you are referring to?

Comment: Same result to console - the "input" is working but the "textarea" outputs the original data not the data after I modify it... so the breal appears to be happening when the update.php receives the data?

Comment: @catcon  We can use val to get first value when load page. But when user change textarea, it don't change text in value attribute

Comment: The text area uses TinyMCE to edit the data in the #bodytext FYI - this seems to be the root of the problem - Tiny MCE works with INPUT but needs to be "saved" on change with js post  being submitted via a TEXTAREA post - looking for the solution now based on this...