# TinyMCE - Adding Event Listeners Issue

Tags: jquery, tinymce, onkeyup

I'm stuck on understanding how to setup event handlers for my `tinymce` editors.
This post may get long, so my apologies.

I'm reading up on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024712/this-keyup-not-responding-when-focused-on-tinymce), which is exactly what I want to do:

I may be instantiating my TinyMCE editor instances in a way that is confusing me with extending it's power.

On my sites, I mostly have my editors doing the most simple, bare-bones work.
And now I'm on a page that I want to reflect `onkeyup` changes to be displayed in `<div id="displayHtml">`
(similar to what SOF is doing)

Here is what I typically have in most my pages:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce_configs.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="displayHtml"></div>

<textarea name="notecomments" id="notecomments" tinymce="tinymce_basic" style="width:650px;height:555px;"></textarea>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('textarea[tinymce]').each(function(){ 
        var tinymceopts = $(this).attr('tinymce');
        $(this).tinymce(window[tinymceopts]); 
    });

     // my failed attempt to add an event
     $(".mceContentBody").on('keyup',function(){
        var htmltxt = $(this).val();
        $("#displayHtml").html(htmltxt);
     });

}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You'll see `tinymce="tinymce_basic"` in my `textarea`.  I globalized calling the tinymce themes and plugins this way.  Works great for me too.

In my tinymce_configs.js file, here's what I've defined:

```
// JavaScript Document
var tinymce_basic = 
{
    script_url : '/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',// Location of TinyMCE script
    // General options
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",
    force_p_newlines : false,
    force_br_newlines : true,
    forced_root_block : false, // Needed for 3.x 
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,hr,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,styleprops,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,removeformat,code,|,preview",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false
}
/* more var options below */
```

So there you have it.  Everything above works well for all my pages with textareas that have the attribute: `tinymce="tinymce_basic"`.
Now it's time to focus on a single page that would look great with all changes in the tinymce to reflect inside the `<div id="displayHtml">`.

My attempt, above, is looking for `.mceContentBody`, which I assumed would work, since the tinymce editor appears to hold the html inside it's iframe with that class.  (Doesn't work)

I get confused with how others are firing up their Tiny MCE editors, since mine doesn't appear to look the same.  Here's Tiny MCE's [onKeyUp example](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onKeyUp).
I've never started anything with `tinyMCE.init({....`

Do I need to change how I'm calling each tinymce editor?
With what I have, how can I reflect the contents of my TinyMCE into another element?

**An Alteration from some Posts below:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('textarea[tinymce]').each(function(){ 
        var tinymceopts = $(this).attr('tinymce');
        $(this).tinymce(window[tinymceopts]); 
    });

     // This was added
     $(".mceContentBody").on('keyup',function(){
            tinymce_basic["setup"] = function(ed) { 
                ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) { 
                     console.debug('Key up event: ' + e.keyCode); });
            }       

     });

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need do it in configuration:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : ...,
    ...,
    setup : function (ed) {
        ed.onKeyPress.add(
            function (ed, evt) {
                alert("Editor-ID: "+ed.id+"\nEvent: "+evt);
                //....
            }
        );
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: That's great, but I don't know where I'm putting that inside what I have already.

Comment: Try add the `setup` callback function into your `var tinymce_basic` object.

Comment: That's my problem, I'm working on a single page that uses the  `tinymce_basic`, and many other pages are too.  Am I able to extend it without changing the `tinymce_configs.js` file?

Comment: Just add: tinymce_basic["setup"] = function(ed) { ... };  That should do it.

Comment: Implement it, how you want. I just solved your problem with configuration.

Comment: I hate to ask, but I really need some more code to show me exactly where.  I admit I'm still quite a novice in this area.

Comment: So extend this object (general for all pages) in specific page by `tinymce_basic.setup = function(ed) { ... };`

Comment: I gave it a shot, and I posted above what I changed on that one page. So far I don't see anything in the console log.  Did I place it correctly?

Comment: Because you added it in event, that will never occur. Place `tinymce_basic.setup = function(ed) { ... };` just in `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: @Athlan, you gotta watch how you talk to others.  Keep it cool, Man

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26809/discussion-between-athlan-and-coffeemonitor)