# How to select form id in jquery code?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to disable submit button until some fields are filled. I've found a code working, but I have several forms in my page, so I'd like to select the form affected by the code...

html:

```
<form id="form_id1">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal</legend>
    Name: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
    Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10" /><br />
    Address : <textarea size="30"></textarea><br />

  </fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<form id="form_id2">
  <fieldset>
<legend>Personal</legend>
Name: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10" /><br />
Address : <textarea size="30"></textarea><br />

  </fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);
    var textCounter = false;
    $('input:text, textarea').keyup(check_submit);

    function check_submit() {
        $('input:text, textarea, select').each(function()
          {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                textCounter = true;
                return false;
               }
            else {
                textCounter = false;
            }
         });

        $('input:submit').attr("disabled", textCounter);
    }
});
```

any idea?
thanks

---

Ok, with the code #form_id1 input:submit before all fields it works on jsfiddle. But not on my page... I found that I'm using tinymce for textarea field, and that is the problem. The button is not activated after filling the textarea field!  If I remove tinymce, it works! Any idea?

---

I've found that tinymce is using iframe for displaying its textarea :-(( is there a way to validate that?...

Comment: "so I'd like to select the form affected by the code" which means? Here, none form fired anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (working on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dx6wU/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);

    $("input:text, textarea, select").bind("keyup blur", function(){
        check_form($(this));
    });

    function check_form(formField){
        var form = formField.closest("form");
        var disableButton = false;
        $.each(form.find("input:text, textarea, select"), function(){
            if($(this).val().length == 0){
                disableButton = true;
            }
        });
        form.find("input:submit").attr("disabled", disableButton);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where it says `$('input:whatever')`, you can use `$('#form_id1 input:whatever')`.

---

**EDIT**

To face the TinyMCE issue with the `keyup` event you shoud add some code to the initializer:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {
          check_submit;
      });
   }
});
```

That binds the same `check_submit` function to the `onKeyUp` event that TinyMCE provides.

You can check the [documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api3%3aevent.tinymce.editor.onkeyup) for more references.

Comment: Yes! That's it, thanks. In jsfiddle it works but not on my form! :-(
I found that I'm using tinymce for textarea field, and that is the problem. The button is not activated after filling the fields! :-( Why?

Comment: Wow, that's a completely different question. Your problem is that TinyMCE needs a particular setup to handle events. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024712/this-keyup-not-responding-when-focused-on-tinymce

Comment: Ok, I've read the thread... But I ca't see how to adapt the code for my case :-( could you help please?

Comment: Well, I've edited, but it's hard to answer without having your TinyMCE code or at least a jsfiddle to check the actual issue.

Comment: If I put the code into tinymce.init, it disable tinymce...
Here is my code (sorry, it doesn't work putting code in comments): http://jsfiddle.net/Q2qqd/ (I use tinyMCE v4 with jquery)

Answer (score 0):

use $("#form_id1 ****")

```
   $('#form_id1 input:text,#form_id1 textarea,#form_id1 select').each(function()
      {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            textCounter = true;
            return false;
           }
        else {
            textCounter = false;
        }
     });

    $('#form_id1 input:submit').attr("disabled", textCounter);
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
element.parent().attr("id");
```

where element is your button object

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/AVsgH/53/

**CODE**

```
$("form").each(function () {
    $(this).find('input:text, textarea, select').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            textCounter = true;
            return false;
        } else {
            textCounter = false;
        }
    });
     $(this).find('input:submit').attr("disabled", textCounter);
});
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd give ids to the form input buttons.
Then you should be able to use jquery closest:

```
$('input[id$="yourbtnid"]').closest("form");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the keyup event callback is attached to **descendants** of form elements you can select the form affected by the code doing:

```
$('input:text, textarea').keyup(check_submit);

function check_submit() {
    // some code
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    // some code 
}
```

**[See this demo in action](http://jsfiddle.net/4Vhms/)**

Comment: the demo highlight the form affected by the code so "keyup" some input or textarea to see it in action